# Thread and serial communication in Win32

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, serial-port

I have a C program for Windows that uses Win32 API, with a main thread and another thread (named ThreadRx) that receives data from a serial port (Virtual COM Port, USB).
The serial port is handled in "overlapped" mode.
The core of the ThreadRx is a while loop:

```
while(is_ThreadRx_Enabled)
{
      //issue a read operation
      //wait for the event "read completed"
      //feed a shared variable
      //other things....
}
ExitThread(0);
```

When I want to close the program, the main thread disables ThreadRx in the following way:

```
is_ThreadRx_Enabled = FALSE; //block rx thread loop
waitFSOretval = WaitForSingleObject(hThreadRx, 2000); //wait max 2s 
switch (waitFSOretval)
{
case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    break; //OK, thread terminated
default: //in any other case (e.g., timeout) force thread termination
    TerminateThread(hThreadRx, 1);
    break;
}
retval = CloseHandle(hThreadRx);
```

Now, if the transmitter connected to the serial port doesn't send data anymore, the reading operation is blocked and so the rxThread termination is forced. Any following operation on the serial port leads to an error (if I try to flush the serial port, I get a blue screen!!!)
What is the correct way to handle this situation?
Is there something like an "abort" function to terminate an issued reading operation?
Many thanks!
Alessio

Comment: usually when you close last handle to file - all io operations is aborted. also exist `CancelIo[Ex]`. also i be on your place not create dedicated thread, but bind serial port to callback via `BindIoCompletionCallback`. again the best way cancel io - close all handles to file

Comment: and use  dedicated thread, which based on your comments in place wait when read complete - *issue a read operation..wait for the event "read completed* - make no sense asynchronous ("overlapped") mode - you yourself implement synchronous mode really - why instead wait in-place yourself - let do this system auto, by using synchronous handle ? if you really want asynchronous processing - you not need wait just after io operation for it complete, but use callbacks/event driven style/ and not need use dedicated threads

Comment: If you use "overlapped mode" then the read should not be blocked.  Do post the stack trace of the blocked thread to get the best advice.